# Drop updates of a file in git

Tags: git, commit

I have made some updates in one file, but I do not need those updates any more before I stage and commit, how could I drop the updates in this file and get the version before updates?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Undoing-Things:

Use `git checkout -- <file>...` to discard changes in working directory.